# Add new special character in tinymce charmap

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using tinymce editor for my project. I want to add some more special characters (for eg Rupee sign (₹)). However I didn't find any solution.

My code is

```
tinymce.init({
            "selector": "#editor",
            "menubar":false,
            "statusbar": false,
            "plugins": "charmap",
            "toolbar": "bold italic underline | charmap"
})
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the options in the character map using either `charmap` or `charmap_append` in your TinyMCE configuration:

`charmap` **entirely replaces** the default character map that TinyMCE uses by default

`charmap_append` **adds new characters** to the default character map that TinyMCE uses by default

For example you could add something like either of these to your TinyMCE configuration:

```
charmap: [["0256","A - kahako"],["0257","a - kahako"],["0274","E - kahako"]]
```

or

```
charmap_append: [["0256","A - kahako"],["0257","a - kahako"]]
```